# Facebook page access token is not working

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am using Graph API for insights stats for facebook page but data array is blank and not returning any value.

```
"data": [

   ]
```

Comment: Did the user access token (that was used to request the page access token) include `read_insights` permission …?

Comment: Yes It has read_insights permission.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference from [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692355/facebook-only-returning-name-and-id-of-user/31692908#31692908)

Looks like you're using v2.4 of the Graph API. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> **Declarative Fields**
>   To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you **explicitly request the field(s) you need** for your GET requests. For example, `GET /v2.4/pageid/insights` no longer includes likes and comments by default, but `GET /v2.4/pageid/insights?fields=id,name,period,values,title,description` will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.