# Facebook only returning name and id of user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth

I am trying to login to my website using my Facebook account but Facebook is giving name and id only that is not enough to login user. Before I was getting full information like firstname, lastname, email etc.

Data provided by facebook now:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => FName LName
    [id] => 236189327864097
)
```

I am using Oauth v2.0 to login users through Facebook to my website.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like you're using v2.4 of the Graph API. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> **Declarative Fields**
>   To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you **explicitly request the field(s) you need** for your GET requests. For example, `GET /v2.4/me/feed` no longer includes likes and comments by default, but `GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes` will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.

To get an idea how to use the so-called field expansion, have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fields

Comment: @RaghubendraSingh Yes, **if**  you're using v2.4.

Comment: added fields in the url called using CallAPI function and the desired results. Relaxed now.

Comment: Thanks for this. I would also suggest that you edit your answer to add this link aiming the phonegap facebook plugin users: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1092

Answer (score 9):

```
FB.api('/me?fields=first_name, last_name, picture, email', function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.first_name + '!';
        });
```

This worked for me. Pass email after /me?fields=  in FB.api request.

Comment: It's not working for the below url   '/me/friends?fields=first_name, last_name, picture, email',

Answer (score 1):

If you using PHP, you need to read also this article:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4

Basically, Fb says about `email` that

> Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed
>   you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for
>   Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email
>   field may be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Pass by parameters the fields that you looking for:

```
var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday,email,name,id"), null, eventArgs.Account);
```