# facebook Email field is missing on AuhtenticationManager.GetExternalInfoAsync

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, owin

Did any of you encountered some issues on facebook api v2.4

Whenever I called AuthenticationManager.GetExternalInfoAsync, the info only returns ID and Name. This did not happened on some of our apps on api v2.3. I also updated the facebook package on nuget but still no luck

I also tried checking the what is returned by facebook through fiddler (graph.facebook.com/me), but I can only see two fields on the returned JSON.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer at

- [Facebook only returning name and id of user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692355/facebook-only-returning-name-and-id-of-user/31692908#31692908)

You have to specify each field now with Graph API v2.4.

Comment: thanks. Seems like I had to deal with Microsoft Owin with this, to add the new parameters.

Comment: No, you have to change your request URL, as described in the answer I linked, so that it includes the fields parameter

Comment: @Tobi, I suspect not all such frameworks/SDKs expose the actual API request that is made to the user; if they handle that in the background, then indeed the code will have to be adapted on the framework/SDK creator’s side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

I kinda make a work around with this, and I needed to make additional codes

```
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        var fbAccessToken = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Where(a => a.Type == "FacebookAccessToken").FirstOrDefault().Value;

        var fbacc = ApiHelper<ExternalAccount>.GetByFullAddress(string.Format(@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}&fields=name,email,first_name,middle_name,last_name", fbAccessToken), null);
```

I hope there will be a cleaner way for this sooner. Again, thanks everyone!