# UserPro Facebook Login Error

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I've been using a Premium WordPress plugin UserPro, and for some reason, the facebook sign-in feature doesn't work. While Twitter and Google+ sign in work perfectly.

Every time I try logging in via facebook it says "Cannot Sign in! Looks like some error with Facebook email id". I've tried logging in via multiple email IDs to no avail.

Apparently its "a problem with my app setup" so could anyone give me tips on how to set up the app for this plugin? Also, is there some sort of issue with Facebook apps and test websites (my website is currently on a webhostbox.net URL and that is the URL I've been entering for the app.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the plugin hasn't been updated to reflect the changes that came with Graph API v2.4. Or, you're using an outdated version. If you pay for that, refer to the creator of the plugin if it's already v2.4 compliant.

See

- [Facebook only returning name and id of user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692355/facebook-only-returning-name-and-id-of-user/31692908#31692908)

Comment: I was afraid that may be the case. I hoped the newest update to the plugin would solve it, seems not. I guess I'll just have to wait for them to get back to me. Thanks for the reply, though. :)