# Login with facebook email is not returned

Tags: ios, facebook

I was using longInWithFacebook in my app, created few months back,

Now I needed to change it with another facebook app id,
I created a new app on facebook.

Now with this new app, only name & fb id is returned and **email is missing**.

I am using

> FBLoginView

I am having this issue since couple of weeks ago. Looks like fb have changed the things recently

[image: It is showing that email is approved item]

Comment: @Dharmesh This issue is being produced with new created apps on https://developers.facebook.com , It is working good with apps created few months back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks `@Tobi` & `@Damian`, your answers helped me to solve this

After hours of struggle, finally got the answer,
FB has just changed the things, now you have to explicitly request for email & other required fields/info of the user

```
FBRequest *me = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me?fields=email,first_name,last_name"];
        [me startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                         NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
                                         NSError *error) {
           NSString* email= [user objectForKey:@"email"];//use this

        }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook have indeed changed things. You no longer get access to a user's email by default, you have to request permission explicitly (and your app probably needs to go through a Facebook review process as well).

Comment: Thanks @damian, please guide me where can I request this permission.

Comment: You don't have to go through review for the standard permissions, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer to a similar question:

- [Facebook only returning name and id of user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692355/facebook-only-returning-name-and-id-of-user/31692908#31692908)

Baseline is that you have to request each field which you want returned explicitly. This was a change with the introdcution of the Graph API v2.4.