# Facebook Oauth with Graph API does not give all information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, python-requests

I'm trying to implement a very basic Oauth transaction script (this one, to be exact: http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/facebook.html)
to communicate with facebook and get user information for user profiles.

Most resources I've looked at, including the facebook docs themselves, have said that default access request includes permissions for "public_profile", which includes things like "firstname", "lastname", "gender", "age", etc. Maybe not those things exactly, but nonetheless, a lot of things.

However, every time I make the transaction, all I get is "name" and "id". Its all I can ever get, even with trying different routes on graph.facebook.com. Even weirder, when I'm asked permission in the OAuth access window, I can see that its asking for permissions for 'email' and 'public_profile'.

I cannot find anyone else having this problem and I have no idea what is wrong. Please help. Here is my exact code:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import facebook_compliance_fix

# Credentials you get from registering a new application
client_id = '<id>'
client_secret = '<secret>'

# OAuth endpoints given in the Facebook API documentation
authorization_base_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth'
token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token'
redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:8080/'     # Should match Site URL
scope = [
    "email"
]

facebook = OAuth2Session(client_id, scope=scope, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
facebook = facebook_compliance_fix(facebook)

# Redirect user to Facebook for authorization
authorization_url, state = facebook.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
print 'Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = raw_input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')

# Fetch the access token
print "\naccess token: "
print facebook.fetch_token(
    token_url, 
    client_secret=client_secret, 
    authorization_response=redirect_response
)
print "\n"

# Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
r = facebook.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me')
print r.content
```

Comment: If you search StackOverflow this questions have been asked at least once per day the last months. You need to specify which fields you want

Comment: Yes, that is true. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WizKid is correct. For > v2.4, one has to explicitly specify the fields they want. 
The appropriate substitute for the call above would be

```
r = facebook.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,picture,email,locale,timezone')
```

another version of this question can be found here: [Facebook only returning name and id of user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692355/facebook-only-returning-name-and-id-of-user)

unsure why id didn't show up sooner after all the googling I was doing on this issue.